# How can I determine if a binary is installed using bash?

Tags: bash

Using Terminal, what's the easiest way to determine if a binary named `dcmdump` is installed on the user's system? If installed I need to know its location (e.g. `/usr/local/bin`) and if its not installed then I'd like the Terminal to echo `FALSE`.

I know very little Terminal script but typing:

```
command -v dcmdump
```

Outputs the directory dcmdump is installed in (if installed - which is great) but nothing is echoed if its not (I want it to echo the string **FALSE**)

Comment: "*but nothing is echoed if it's not*" -- and that's how you can tell it's not installed. Why is printing `FALSE` more useful? Incidentally, Terminal is just a terminal enumerator; it just lets you enter and display text. It's the shell that provides the ability to actually do stuff.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a program exists from a bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script)

Comment: Are you planning on running the command if it *is* installed? If so, it's easiest to just try to run it, and if the exit status is 126 or 127, tell the user to install it and exit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$ which dcmdump 2>/dev/null || echo FALSE
```

Here is how it works:

- The entire expression is a boolean OR (written as `||`) of two commands.  The left-hand-side of the OR is the command `which dcmdump 2>/dev/null`, the right-hand-side is `echo FALSE`.
- Thanks to lazy evaluation (or short-circuiting), if the left-hand-side evaluates to “true” (or “success”), then the right-hand-side will not be evaluated.  Otherwise, it will.
- The command `which NAME` looks for an executable named `NAME` in your current shell `$PATH`.  If it finds one, it prints its absolute path to the standard output and exits with a status indicating “success”, otherwise, it might or might not print an error message to the standard error output and returns a status indicating “failure”.
- Since we don't want `which`'s error message but our own, we redirect `which`'s standard error output to the black hole `/dev/null` with the `2>/dev/null` part.
- The command `echo TEXT` simply outputs `TEXT` to the standard output.  If you wanted `FALSE` to be printed to the standard error output, you could redirect it using `echo FALSE >&2`.

Answer (score 7):

On OS X at least, doing `which dcmdump` to have it say `/usr/local/bin/dcmdump` (if it finds the command) is not absolutely bad. But [there can be issues with using `which` in other environments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/677212/441757).

But the main ding against `which` in general is, it’s a separate command that’s not built into the shell, and so-called [shell “builtins”](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html) are better choices when they get the job done just as well.

So if all you want is to check if a command exists (and don’t need to know where it is), you can get that just with the `hash dcmdump` builtin and examining the return value; e.g., `echo $?`, or:

```sh
if hash dcmdump 2>/dev/null; then
  echo "OK, you have dcmdump installed. We’ll use that."
else
  echo "You need dcmdump. I can install if for you, OK?"
  read -e -p "Y or N? " yn
  if [[ "y" = "$yn" || "Y" = "$yn" ]]; then
    ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
    brew install dcmtk
  else
    echo "We need dcmdump. Stopping."
    exit
  fi
fi
```

None of the options for checking command existence return a literal string **FALSE** (as you ask in your question); but using `hash dcmdump` and just checking the return value will get the job done.

And if you do want to know where exactly the command is, that’s what `command -v` will give you. Using `type dcmdump` will also give you that info, in a slightly different form.

Anyway, `hash` and `command -v` and `type` are all shell built-ins, so that’s in part why they’re recommended over `which` for this. The [canonical answer on this at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/677212/441757) gives more details.

btw, if your goal is to get `dcmdump` on your system, you can do that by installing [homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

And then after that, you can install the `dcmtk` package:

```
brew install dcmtk
```

And then you really will have a `dcmdump` command in `/usr/local/bin/dcmdump`.

Comment: I've seen on SO that using the `which` command is not a good idea hence why I thought the `command -v` approach is better. Problem is, I have no idea how to do an if...else clause in the Terminal

Comment: Ah, about that, actually, using `hash` is best. I’ll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on getting dcmtk - figured that out yesterday (took ages!). I actually need a way to check if a user has installed dcmtk on their system (if not, my app will prompt them to).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `which` and check if the return value is null like bellow:

```
#!/bin/sh
bi=$(which $1)
if [ -z $bi ]
then
    echo "FALSE"
else
    echo $bi
fi
```

Then the script can be run like this:

`./script command`

Answer (score 1):

[POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-can-i-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script) compatible:

```
command -v dcmdump || echo FALSE
```

or use the below if you need to reuse the path

```
if cmd=$(command -v dcmdump); then echo $cmd; else echo FALSE; fi
```